# Disable weekends on calendarextender

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know if there is a simple solution to disable weekends from calendarextender in asp.net.

I saw this:
[first link](http://www.go4answers.com/Example/disable-weekends-ajax-calendar-extender-94762.aspx)
[second link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/309731-How-disable-week-ends-ajax-calendar-extendar.aspx)

But it didnt help me:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="TextBox1"  OnClientShown="DisableWeekends" runat="server">
</asp:CalendarExtender>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisableWeekends(sender, args)
    {
         for(var i=0; i<sender._days.all.length; i++)
        {
                  for(var j=0; j<6; j++)
                 {
                        if(sender._days.all[i].id == "calendarValidToDate_day_"+j+"_0")
                       {
                              sender._days.all[i].disabled = true;
                              sender._days.all[i].innerHTML = "<div>" +sender._days.all[i].innerText+ "</div>";
                        }

                        if(sender._days.all[i].id == "calendarValidToDate_day_"+j+"_6")
                       {
                                sender._days.all[i].disabled = true;
                                sender._days.all[i].innerHTML = "<div>" +sender._days.all[i].innerText+ "</div>";
                       }
                }
         }
    }

</script>
```

Any tips?

Comment: I am currently using C#

Comment: I think the code from your `second link` will works  , check your code again , but If you need more , you can reference http://irfanyar.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/disable-weekends-for-ajaxtoolkit-calendar-extender/ , and http://net-ajax.itags.org/q_dotnet-ajax_18772.html

Comment: Yes I already tried that code but nothing happens..

Comment: So , can you show me your code ? what have you tried ?

Comment: ok here you have my code

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript as like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DisableWeekends(sender, args)
{
     for(var i=0; i<sender._days.all.length; i++)
    {
              for(var j=0; j<6; j++)
             {
                    if(sender._days.all[i].id == "CalendarExtender1_day_"+j+"_0")
                   {
                          sender._days.all[i].disabled = true;
                          sender._days.all[i].innerHTML = "<div>" +sender._days.all[i].innerText+ "</div>";
                    }

                    if(sender._days.all[i].id == "CalendarExtender1_day_"+j+"_6")
                   {
                            sender._days.all[i].disabled = true;
                            sender._days.all[i].innerHTML = "<div>" +sender._days.all[i].innerText+ "</div>";
                   }
            }
     }
}
```

Your calendar extendar's ID is `CalendarExtender1` , but in your javascript , you use `calendarValidToDate` likes example code ! I think this is point .
Good Luck :)

Comment: Indeed it should be better! But unfortunately it still doesn't work. I can still choose weekends date

Comment: When I try to insert an alert in the script it doesn't work either. I guess values like sender._days.all.length aren't recognized: alert(sender._days.all.length) doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing some references?

Comment: humm , `<asp:CalendarExtender>` ? Don't you use `<AJAXControl:CalendarExtender>` ?

Comment: No ajaxcontrol isn't recognized. <asp:CalendarExtender> works well. Do you think thats the problem?